# Send JavaScript array to PHP array via jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a JavaScript array via jQuery Ajax to a new PHP array:

```
var heart = [31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,42,43];

$('#find_btn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'scripts/get_specimens_system.php',
        data: {
                system: heart,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#search_list_container').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

In the PHP script I have the following before a MySQL query:

```
$system = array($_POST['system']);
```

If I hardcode the data in `heart` like:

```
$system = array(31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,42,43);
```

the query works OK. What am I doing wrong?

In an attempt to simplify the question I have left out the fact that I'm setting the JS array to `var system` via `system = $(this).attr('data-system');`

Where the data-system is set to the arrays like:

```
$('#sub_category_box_systems').html("<a class='sub_category_link' href='#' data-subcat-type='system' data-system='" + brain + "'>Brain</a><br /><hr><a class='sub_category_link' href='#' data-subcat-type='system' data-system='" + nerves + "'>Nerves</a><br /><hr><a class='sub_category_link' href='#' data-subcat-type='system' data-system='" + cerebellum + "'>Cerebellum</a>");
```

Now if I alert `system` just before the AJAX statement the alert shows the intergers fine.

```
$('#sub_category_box_systems').on('click', '.sub_category_link', function() {
    system = $(this).attr('data-system');
});


$('#find_btn').click(function(){
    alert(system);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'scripts/get_specimens_system.php',
        data: {
            system: system,
        },
        success: function(data) {
        }
    });
});
```

AND I have updated the PHP file to:

```
$system = $_POST['system'];
```

Still no go, though if I swap the var `system` with the actual var of an array (for example, `heart`), as the Ajax data it works. So what's wrong here? (sorry for changing this OP...).

Odd, if I change var `system` to a specific array like below it works, so there must be some problem with the formatting using the jQuery `.attr('data-system');`

```
$('#sub_category_box_systems').on('click', '.sub_category_link', function() {
    system = heart;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding an extra array around the parameter, which is already an array. Just do:

```
$system = $_POST['system'];
```

Comment: Or if trying to send a multi-dimensional array, use $system[0]

Comment: Only if he just wants the first row of it.

Comment: In an attempt to simplify the question I have omitted the fact that I'm getting the JS array via an html data tag and using system = $(this).attr('data-system');  Should I update the OP or open a new question?

Comment: Where the array comes from is irrelevant. An array is an array.

Comment: @Barmar, yup. $system[0] would only pull the first index of the multi-dimensional array. In this case, it is what the OP would need since we see no other information.

Comment: You're talking about a different application. If he's sending a multi-dimensional array (rather than the array in the question), what would you think he only cares about the first dimension?

Answer (score 3):

By default, jQuery `$.ajax` will submit your request as form data. If you open your browser debugger while the request is sent, you would see this request data:

```
system[]:31
system[]:32
system[]:33
system[]:34
system[]:35
system[]:36
system[]:37
system[]:38
system[]:39
system[]:42
system[]:43
```

PHP understands that this is an array and reads it in as an array by default. **You should not wrap it in an `array()` tag.**

You can assign the array to your own variable as such: **`$system = $_POST['system'];`**

However, your work isn't quite done there. `$system` is now an **array of strings**. Here is a `var_dump` of `$system`:

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "31"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "32"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "33"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "34"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "35"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "36"
  [6]=>
  string(2) "37"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "38"
  [8]=>
  string(2) "39"
  [9]=>
  string(2) "42"
  [10]=>
  string(2) "43"
}
```

Use this to convert it to an **array of integers**:

`$system = array_map('intval', $system);`

Comment: It's not really necessary to convert them to integers, since PHP will usually convert strings to numbers when necessary.

Comment: The pitfalls of relying on the loosely typed variables are many. I'm not advocating strong typing for a simple web app, but it certainly is good practice to keep your numbers set as numbers and your strings set as strings. If I were the OP, I would've changed the data type of the POST to application/json so it's clear to PHP that his data is either numeric or a string.

Answer (score 0):

I awarded the answer to `@Barmar` as his solution solved the original OP.  I still had a problem with getting the JS arrays across to the PHP array due to using `system = $(this).attr('data-system')`.  Changing the code to the following fixed that issue:

```
$('#sub_category_box_systems').on('click', '.sub_category_link', function() {       
    system = $(this).attr('data-system').split(",");   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert that to a string by saying:

```
data: {
    system: heart.join(",")
}
```

And converting back to an array on the server side by saying:

```
$system = explode(",",$_POST['system']);
```